# can we change time interval (500 miliseconds) of wait.until in WebDriver Sampler

Tags: selenium, jmeter, webdriver

My script waiting for toast message after clicking button.

```
wait.until(ui.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(pkg.By.xpath("//*[@id='btnSubmitt']")))
```

but i have seen below message
Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by

```
By.xpath: //*[@id='btnSubmitt']
```

(tried for 1 second(s) with **500 milliseconds interval**)

Problem: want to change time interval 500 milliseconds to 50 milliseconds.
so script should check for expected element on every 50 ms interval.

Issue: My script getting more response time than Performance tab  under developer tools in chrome browser.

Comment: You can try something fluent wait https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
var wait = new org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 1000).pollingEvery(50, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

should do the trick for you.

References:

- [FluentWait.pollingEvery()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html#pollingEvery-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)
- [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered)
- [WebDriver Implicit, Explicit and Fluent Wait Examples](https://devqa.io/webdriver-explicit-implicit-fluent-wait/)